# Retornar valor de imagem

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho este código html:

```
<label>
     <img class="jogo" value="lol" src="../cdn/img/jogos/lol.png">
     <img class="jogo" value="csgo" src="../cdn/img/jogos/csgo.png">
</label>
<br><div class="atual"> </div>
```

Eu queria que no div debaixo mostrasse o valor das imagens em cima ( lol /csgo )

```
$(function(){
 $(".jogo").click(function(){

    $(".jogo").animate({opacity:0.5},{duration:100});
    $(this).animate({opacity:1},{duration:100});
    var jogo = $(this).val();
    $(".atual").html(jogo);
 });
});
```

Não sei como que faço isso :/

Codigo jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/xj1L52h3/

**______________________________________________**

**Editado**

Estou com outra duvida, eu queria fazer com que, quando clicasse em 1 das imagens aparecesse um menu e quando clicasse na outra, desaparecesse o que ja lá estava e aparecesse outro.

http://jsfiddle.net/xj1L52h3/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei exatamente porque não funcionou mas suspeito que seja porque a tag `img` não trabalha com o atributo `value`. Esse atributo é usado em elementos de formulário. Então se você trocar o `.val()` para `.attr("value")` vai resolver.

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xj1L52h3/1/)**</kbd>

Mas o correto nesse caso é utilizar os atributos [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), exemplo:

```
<img class="jogo" data-game="lol" src="../cdn/img/jogos/lol.png" />
<img class="jogo" data-game="csgo" src="../cdn/img/jogos/csgo.png" />
```

E então para acessar o atributo:

```
$(this).data("game")
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xj1L52h3/2/)**</kbd>

Sobre o efeito da imagens, eu gostaria de sugerir que você usasse esse seletor:

```
$(".jogo").not(this).animate({opacity:0.5},{duration:100});
```

Pois assim você não executa esta animação em todos as imagens, apenas nas que não foram clicadas.

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xj1L52h3/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, pensei a mesma coisa sobre a tag `img` não trabalhar com o `value`, mas n sabia como resolver. Obrigado :)

Comment: Editei ali o tópico, tem como me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: @xdam98 http://jsfiddle.net/xj1L52h3/8/

Comment: Obrigado, deu tudo certo.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que pegar o atributo "src" da imagem com o .attr do jQuery, segue o código corrigo:

http://jsfiddle.net/bxcvahko/2/

```
$(function(){

    $(".jogo").click(function(){

        $(".jogo").animate({opacity:0.5},{duration:100});
        $(this).animate({opacity:1},{duration:100});
        var jogo = $(this).attr('src');

        jogo = jogo.slice(jogo.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, jogo.length);
        jogo = jogo.split('.')[0];

        $(".atual").html(jogo);
    });

});
```

Comment: o usuario @DontVoteMeDown fez o mesmo de uma maneira mais simples. Entretanto, obrigado, esse "split" vai-me ser util no futuro :D

Comment: Um regex aí melhoraria muito esse código.